# How can i check if a certain line in console is empty?

Tags: c++, io, console, cout

Im making a little chat application in c++ using winsocks and the tcp protocol, i made a little username system to make things easier but i have the following problem. [image: The "error"]

And well, i think i got the solution but I didn't find any way to check if the line where we going to print its empty or not. If it is empty, we print there, if its not we jump to the next line, but as I said I havent found any way to do it.

Code:

```
std::string Message;    
            if (!GetString(Message))          
                return false;       
            std::cout  << Message << std::endl; // here i need to check the line where we will print the message
            break;
```

-kaoti

Comment: `if(Message.empty()) { ... } else { ... }` ?

Comment: Unclear question. You want to check user input not empty?

Comment: What is the problem you're having in the screenshot?

Comment: For instance, i want to check if the line where it writes Kaoti: its empty, if it is, print there the message that sended the other clients, if its not print it to the next line

Comment: C++ doesn't remember what is on a give line in an output stream. once written, it's gone. If you want to remember if a line is empty, you'll have to do it yourself. But... C++'s streams do not know how to skip a line or go back a line or do anything remotely complicated. They just write one character after another because that's what streams do. It sounds like you might want to look into a console library like [one of the curses family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) to handle more complicated text display needs.

Comment: In this case it might be easier to keep track of chat messages and control messages separately. Both get written to the console, but only the chat messages are sent to other chatters.

Comment: Thats a good idea user4581301, i will try to do it manually, thanks you!